# Excel VBA Vlookup returning - Error 2042

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I'm trying to do a Vlookup but it is returning Error 2042, even if there is a match. I cannot figure out what is wrong with the code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Private Sub F6P_SORT()

Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("MTD")

On Error Resume Next
Dim Table1 As Range
Dim Table2 As Range
Dim Table3 As Range

Dim IniName_Row As Long
Dim IniName_Clm As Long

LastRow = targetSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Set Table1 = targetSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow) ' CC/IO from MTD
Set Table3 = targetSheet.Range("F2:F" & LastRow) ' Ini Name to MTD

Set sourceSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("IO Lookup")
LastRow = sourceSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Set Table2 = Sheet1.Range("A2:D" & LastRow) ' IO from IO Lookup


IniName_Row = Table3.Row
IniName_Clm = Table3.Column

For Each cl In Table1
    targetSheet.Cells(IniName_Row, IniName_Clm) = Application.VLookup(cl, Table2.Value, 4, False)
    IniName_Row = IniName_Row + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Where's the error occurring? at the `targetSheet.Cells(...` line in the `For each cl`  loop?

Comment: remove the `.Value` from the `Table2.Value` in the VLookup.  It needs the range not the value of the range.

Comment: error is at "targetSheet.Cells(IniName_Row, IniName_Clm) = Application.VLookup(cl, Table2.Value, 4, False)"

Comment: I was using it without .Value and it was not working then I read somewhere that it needs .Value with range object. And somehow it worked but then I copy pasted it to another sub, and it stopped working.

Comment: That error means it is not finding a match, so either you are looking in the wrong column, your lookup value is not in column A, or you have unprintable characters in your data that is making it so there are no matches but look the same.  Look at your data.

Comment: I cannot find anything wrong with the data. Can I replace
    targetSheet.Cells(IniName_Row, IniName_Clm) = Application.VLookup(cl, Table2.Value, 4, False)

with Index Match, if yes can anyone translate this to Index Match. I have just started working with VBA, so its quite difficult to figure it out.

Comment: Why are you using **sourceSheet** to define the last row then switching to **Sheet1** to define the range? Is Sheet1 the codename of sourceSheet?

Comment: Thank you so much, I first wrote the code on a different sheet and then copied it to another and forgot to change this line. Its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change this line:

```
Set Table2 = Sheet1.Range("A2:D" & LastRow)
```

to:

```
Set Table2 = sourceSheet.Range("A2:D" & LastRow)
```

your code will work

You should also add Option Explicit to the top of every module to force variable declaration.  `cl` hadn't been declared as `Range`!